# 2D array of pointers: Deleting the array but not the pointers?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management, heap-memory

In my code, I have a 2D array of pointers to my data:

```
Data***
```

The reason I'm not using array notation is because the size is not determined at compile time.
So, somewhere in my code I allocate all the necessary space:

```
arr = new Data **[xVals];
for (int i = 0; i < xVals; i++)
{
    arr[i] = new Data *[yVals];
    for (int j = 0; j < yVals; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = nullptr;
    }
}
```

And then fill the array with my proper pointers some time later on.
Furthermore, the pointer also gets stored in a `std::vector`:

```
for(...) {
    for(...) {
        // Conditional statement; not the whole array gets filled, some parts stay nullptr
        ...
        arr[xCoord][yCoord] = new Data(...);
        myVector.push_back(arr[xCoord][yCoord]);
    }
}
... // Do some other stuff that takes advantage of the spatial properties of the 2D array
```

Once I'm done using the 2D array, I want to delete it, but NOT delete the Data-pointers themselves, since they are now stored in my vector.
I've been trying the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < xVals; i++)
{
    // Delete all "column" arrays
    delete[] arr[i];
}
// Delete 
delete[] arr;
```

However, I get a corrupted heap error `CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer`, so I'm not sure what exactly I did wrong there. How do I delete a 2D array without deleting the data it held?

Comment: Whoever voted to close the question literally a second after I posted it, mind explaining why? I don't think it violates a guideline, nor should a second have been enough to actually read the post.

Comment: Just because you got a corrupted heap message when you deleted stuff doesn't mean that the deletion caused the corruption. The corruption probably occured earlier in code you haven't shown us and was only **detected** when you did the deletes. In fact this is common. Your deletion code looks OK to me, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @john Ah I see, that makes sense. I thought since MSVC pointed my error to the deletes they were the reason for it.

Comment: If you can't spot the problem then start removing code. When you remove a line of code and the error goes away then **probably** that's the line of code that is causing the corruption.

Comment: Don't write `new` and `delete` yourself. Just don't do that, really. There's no need. `std::vector` works. Use it.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I usually avoid doing so using smart pointers, but the particular structure of such an easy-access 2D array happened to be really convenient for this one usecase, especially syntactically.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your motivation. `new` and `delete` and loops and stuff are more convenient that `std::vector`? Really? You have a dozen lines of fragile code that can be replaced by a single line of `std::vector` initialisation.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Mainly because of the "spatial" structure of it -- Some properties of my data happen to be dependent on the 4 neighbors of it (up down left right), which are really easy to query in a 2D array. In a vector, I'd have to be much more careful with my indexing of values to query time with something like y*i+x. Well, that's possible too though so I get your point.

Comment: I meant a vector of vectors. It is still one line.